# False proof that $\operatorname{Spec}(\prod_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb F_2)$ is discrete

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

Vakil says in his book that [the connected components of $\operatorname{Spec}(\prod_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb F_2)$ are not open](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf#page=124#)
 (page 124). But when I try to verify it, I feel like the space is discrete (which contradicts to his statement).

The prime ideals of $\prod_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb F_2$ are $e_i$'s, where $e_i$ is a product of rings whose $i$th component is $0$ while all other components are $\mathbb F_2$.

The topology, I (falsely) claim, is discrete. $\{e_1\}=V(e_1)$ is closed. $\{e_1\}$ is open since its complement is $V((1,0,0,\dots))$.

I can't tell where my argument is wrong and I wonder what this topological space really looks like.

Comment: Consider $I=\oplus_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{F}_2\subset \prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{F}_2$. Then $I$ is a proper ideal, so must be contained in some maximal ideal by Zorn's lemma. Is it contained in any of the prime ideal you write down above?

Comment: @Mohan   oh~~~I see....So how to find all prime ideals of $\prod_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb F_2$?

Comment: I do not know whether one can write them all down. Probably you should try another approach to prove what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your claim about the prime ideals is just incorrect; note that you haven't proven it at all, just claimed it. The prime ideals agree with the maximal ideals and they correspond to [ultrafilters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafilter) on $\mathbb{N}$, of which there are uncountably many. The resulting topology on the spectrum is the topology of the [Stone-Cech compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification) $\beta \mathbb{N}$ of $\mathbb{N}$. See [this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2010/11/22/boolean-rings-ultrafilters-and-stones-representation-theorem/) for details.

Note that the spectrum is always compact so it could not possibly have been an infinite discrete space.